# Moving WordPress to a different directory - update XML Post File?

Tags: xml

OK, I am moving our WordPress install to the root of the domain. I've tested on a cloned version of the site that if I export and import the posts then they all load correctly - except for the fact that all the URL's are now wrong.

Should I edit each of the  tags to make them correct?

```
    <item>
    <title>Title Of Example Blog Post</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com/blog/example-post/</link>
    <pubDate>Sat, 03 Nov 2012 09:45:38 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Admin]]></dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.example.com/blog/?p=79</guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded>
```

So - if you see the third tag down is  - should I (manually) change the URL in the  tag to the correct path?

The reason I ask is because I have done research that shows that the GUID Permalink should remain 'as is' - but I am not sure about the  tag.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Do you mean _all_ URLs are wrong or _some_ of them are wrong, such as those used in content?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend changing the XML file.

When you move the WordPress installation to your root directory, you want to change the **WordPress URL** and **Site URL** options in your **Admin > Settings**.

See official [WordPress Codex page about Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for more details.

You can also manually change "siteurl" and "home" in the database table "wp_options" (through phpMyAdmin or similar).

Comment: OK thanks - so - does changing the SITE URL also change all Posts' URL as well?

Comment: Yes. The WordPress URL is where your WordPress installation lives, and the Site URL is what your website considers home.

For example, you might have your WordPress installation living at www.example.com/wordpress. If that's the case, then your WordPress URL will be www.example.com/wordpress, and your Site URL will be www.example.com.

Or if your WordPress installation lives at www.example.com, then both your WordPress URL and Site URL will be www.example.com.

Whatever comes after the Site URL, (the permalink of posts and pages, etc.), should be fine if it's left on it's own.

Comment: Remember to take a backup of your functioning website before making major changes like this.